# Comparisons in Multiple Sorting Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, random

Currently this program will generate 10 random numbers and either sort (from least to greatest), reverse sort, or shuffle them. However, when trying to list the number of comparisons made, the number of comparisons printed out are completely incorrect. For example, it prints that there were 44 comparisons with bubble sort (this is the one that varies every time but is usually around 40), 45 with selection sort, and 9 with insertion sort. For now I'm only running the program with numbersSorted() just to make sure the comparisons work.
How can I print the correct number of comparisons made with each sorting method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int count1 = 0; //bubble
int count2 = 0; //selection
int count3 = 0; //insertion

vector<int> numbersSorted(int n);
vector<int> numbersReversed(int n);
vector<int> numbersShuffled(int n);

int main() {
srand(time(0));



    numbersSorted(10);
  //numbersReversed(10);
  //numbersShuffled(10);


return 0;
}

vector<int> numbersSorted(int n)
{

vector <int> v(n);

for (auto &x : v)
    x = rand() % 100;

cout << "Original list to be sorted: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout  << x << " ";
cout << "\n\n";

// bubble sort
bool swapped = true;
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2 && swapped; ++pass)
{
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - pass - 2; ++i)
    {
        ++count1;
        if (v.at(i) > v.at(i + 1))
        {
            swap(v[i], v[i + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
cout << "Bubble sort sorted: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count1 << " comparisons with bubble sort.\n" << 
endl;

// selection sort
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2; ++pass)
{
    // Find least element remaining in the list starting at index pass
    int minIndex = pass;
    // i = minIndex + 1, minIndex + 1, ..., n - 1
    for (int i = minIndex + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        ++count2;

        if (v[i] < v[minIndex])
        {
            minIndex = i;

        }
            // The element at index i is smaller than what I thought was the 
min
    }

    swap(v[pass], v[minIndex]);
}
cout << "Selection sort sorted: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count2 << " comparisons with selection sort.\n" << 
endl;


//insertion sort
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2; ++pass) {
    // Take the element at pass+1 and move it to the left until it's in the
    // right spot (i.e., as long as it's in the wrong spot).

    // for i = pass, pass-1, ..., 0 while L[i] > L[i+1]
    ++count3;
    for (int i = pass; i >= 0 && v[i] > v[i + 1]; --i) {
        swap(v[i], v[i + 1]);
    }
}
cout << "Insertion sort sorted: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count3 << " comparisons with insertion sort.\n" << 
endl;
//return v;
}
vector<int> numbersReversed(int n)
{
vector <int> v(n);

for (auto &x : v)
    x = rand() % 100;

cout << "Original list to be reversed: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n\n";


// bubble sort
bool swapped = true;
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2 && swapped; ++pass)
{
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - pass - 2; ++i)
    {
        ++count1;
        if (v.at(i) > v.at(i + 1))
        {
            swap(v[i], v[i + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}

//reverse the content of the vector
reverse(v.begin(),v.end());

cout << "Bubble sort reversed: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count1 << " comparisons with bubble sort.\n" << 
endl;


// selection sort
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2; ++pass)
{
    // Find least element remaining in the list starting at index pass
    int minIndex = pass;
    // i = minIndex + 1, minIndex + 1, ..., n - 1
    for (int i = minIndex + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        ++count2;
        if (v[i] < v[minIndex])
            // The element at index i is smaller than what I thought was the 
min
            minIndex = i;
    }

    swap(v[pass], v[minIndex]);
}

reverse(v.begin(),v.end());

cout << "Selection sort reversed: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count2 << " comparisons with selection sort.\n" << 
endl;



// insertion sort
for (int pass = 0; pass <= n - 2; ++pass) {
    // Take the element at pass+1 and move it to the left until it's in the
    // right spot (i.e., as long as it's in the wrong spot).

    // for i = pass, pass-1, ..., 0 while L[i] > L[i+1]
    ++count3;
    for (int i = pass; i >= 0 && v[i] > v[i + 1]; --i) {
        swap(v[i], v[i + 1]);
    }
}

reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
cout << "Insertion sort reversed: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count3 << " comparisons with insertion sort.\n" << 
endl;

}

vector<int> numbersShuffled(int n)
{
vector<int> v(n);

for (auto &x : v)
{
    x = rand() % 100;
    ++count1;
}


cout << "Numbers Shuffled: ";
for (auto x : v)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "There were " << count1 << " comparisons made. " << endl;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the values are incorrect? Have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Comment: I know the values are incorrect because when there are a higher number of items in the vector (say 50), it says there are thousands of comparisons every time.

Comment: So you're guessing that the number of comparisons should be different? How did you determine that?

Comment: The numbers for insertion sort will be too low because you increment the count once but loop many times.

Comment: These are n^2 sorting algorithms, so if the data gets 5x larger you'd expect the number of comparisons to get 25x larger. 40*25=1000.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the comparison values from growing that quickly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773166/bubble-sort-comparison-count-is-always-the-same

Comment: The only way is to use a different algorithm that has a lower complexity. Perhaps that realization is the point of the exercise?

Comment: One of the problems with your test is that you're not re-shuffling the array between sorts. So after bubblesort is done, you're running selection sort on an already sorted array. If you were to change the order of your tests, you'd find that bubblesort is completing in a single pass. And insertion sort is running so quickly because the array you're feeding it is already sorted: the best case for insertion sort. You need to shuffle the numbers between sorts.